# Boolean not working in Logic App condition

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps

What is the proper way to use booleans in Logic Apps conditions? If the bool is set to true, the workflow should continue in the YES branch but I allways end up with this error-message :

ActionBranchingConditionNotSatisfied. The execution of template action 'HTTP' skipped: the branching condition for this action is not satisfied.

```
{
    "reservations": {
    "sendBooking": true
}}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you switch to "Advanced mode" in the condition card, you should see the expression looks like `@equals(triggerBody()?['sendBooking'], 'true')`

Update it to `@equals(triggerBody()?['sendBooking'], true)` and your logic should work.

This is because, by default, we treat `true` as a string, but in this case it needs to be a Boolean.

Workaround above should unblock you, I will discuss with the team to see how can be better handle this scenario.

Comment: That does not work either, "Condition is too complex or invalid. Unable to switch to basic mode."@equals(triggerBody()?['reservations']?['sendBooking'], true)

Comment: The error message shows up to indicate condition card unable to switch back to basic view, but you should be able to save and run the Logic Apps regardless of this particular message.

Comment: @DerekLi When will this be fixed and is there a better way to go about it? Should we use a boolean variable?

Comment: Doing this fix shows "fx true" in the Basic view, because it's recognized as an expression, but I can't find true in the expressions list.

Comment: you can either use @bool('true'), or true, we will add true and false to the list soon.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround was to remove the '' in code view, then I was able to save the logic app. But the error still exists in the designer.

[image]

[image]